# POST com angular 5

Tags: post, typescript, angular

então, eu estou tentando fazer um app com angular 5 usando auth com token.
Pra isso, no login, eu preciso fazer um post na minha API (que testei pelo postman e está funcionando), mas estou com dificuldades em fazer isso com o angular. Meu código é o seguinte:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    var headers = new Headers({
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json"
    });

    let postData = {
        grant_type: "password",
        client_id: 2,
        client_secret: "RGNmOzt7WQ8SdNiCcJKKDoYrsFqI2tudopFjOJU3",
        username: "albanafmeti@gmail.com",
        password: "password",
        scope: ""
    }

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/oauth/token', JSON.stringify(postData), {
        headers: headers
    })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
        let token = response.json() && response.json().token;
        if (token) {
            // set token property
            this.token = token;

            // store username and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username, token: token }));

            // return true to indicate successful login
            return true;
        } else {
            // return false to indicate failed login
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Como eu sou novo no angular 5, não consegui debugar ele direito, ele não entra no .map e não consigo pegar alguma exception pra entender o q está errado.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema era no CORS do meu app. Assim que coloquei a autorização no cors funcionou :D